# How to ensure an image in a directory is refreshed after it's altered?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I am currently creating a Java web app using Spring and Thymeleaf to encrypt a user-provided image with AES and output a scrambled version. However, when I try to display the image after saving the image to a file, it doesn't seem to update yet and I get an error that the file doesn't exist. Yet when I check my directory, it clearly has. I am fairly new to Thymeleaf and Spring.

I've tried using Thread.sleep in order to allow the image to load. Unfortunately it didnt change anything. I store my images in a static folder.

My Java code is as follows:

```
String path = new File("src/main/resources/static").getAbsolutePath();
File outputFile = new File(path + "/output.jpg");
try {
  outputFile.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.out.println("FILE ALREADY EXISTS");
}

try {
  ImageIO.write(outputImage, "jpg", outputFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

model.addAttribute("image", "output.jpg");
```

My relevant HTML code looks like this:

```
<img th:src="${image}"/>
```

If i pass in the image again it displays the image, but if I pass in another image, it displays the first. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser probably caches the image (stores it locally to prevent downloading it again in the future). You can easily verify this fact by opening your browser debugger (F12), and find the option to disable the cache. There are various ways to solve this issue programmatically:

---

The easiest solution is to rename your image everytime you alter the file, and serve the URL with this unique filename.

```
File outputFile = new File(path + "/output-" + LocalDateTime.now() + ".jpg");
```

---

If you don't mind that the image gets downloaded again everytime the page is displayed, you can invalidate the browser cache with a variable parameter in the URL.

```
model.addAttribute("image", "output.jpg?i=" + LocalDateTime.now());
```

---

Using cache-control with an **ETag**, which involves that your image is not static and should be managed by a controller. Here is an example with a byte buffer:

```
private static final CacheControl CACHE_CONTROL = CacheControl.noCache().cachePrivate().mustRevalidate();

@GetMapping(value = "/image", produces = { MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(WebRequest webRequest) {
    byte[] imageBytes = // Load or generate the image bytes here
    String eTagId     = // Generate a unique eTagId for each version of your image
    if (webRequest.checkNotModified(eTagId))
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED).body(null);

    return ResponseEntity.ok().cacheControl(CACHE_CONTROL).eTag(eTagId).body(imageBytes);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but unfortunately, after disabling the cache, nothing changed